# How to create more than one option for option

Tags: html, reactjs

Is there a way to give an option optionS ?
I'm using CSelect to make options. One of the options should contain options too.

```
<CSelect custom name="select_pattern_filter" id="select_pattern_filter" onChange={onChange} >
  <option value="" defaultValue>Veuillez sélectionner</option>
  <option value="opt1">op1</option>
  <option value="opt2">opt2</option>
  <option value="op3">op3</option>
</CSelect>
```

The opt3 should contain 2 options.
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: optgroup?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "give an option options"? Option groups are only logical groupings of options. It sort of sounds like you want "sub-options". Otherwise, just add a fourth option to the flat list of options.

Answer (score 0):

you could add another  tag to the opt3; the same way you would treat a list inside another list.

```
<ul>
    <li>List one</li>
    <li>
        <ul>
        <li>List inside</li>
        <li>List inside</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of to do this is via arrays or objects

See previous example:

`<select name="">`

`<option value='{"num_sequence":[0,1,2,3]}'>Option one</option>`

`<option value='{"foo":"bar","one":"two"}'>Option two</option></select>`

Comment: Thank, i think ill try optGroup ( I didn't know that they exist :O )